# how to remove repository from svn

Tags: php, svn, project

Q1. hi, i'm created svn for my project and create repository like /var/svn/myproject
    but now i want to delete this repository from the svn. so, please help me about how to 
    delete this repo.

Q2. and my second question is how to upload my project on the svn directory.

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I also wanted to remove a repository. I used VisualSVN to do so.

http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/

I hope it works!

---

Your second question is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Q1:

```
svn delete /var/svn/myproject -m "comment"
```

Q2:

```
svn import myproject protocol://path_to_your_repository/myproject -m "comment"
```

Comment: thanks to answer, but when i'm trying this delete code "svn delete /var/svn/project" i got error message "svn: '/' is not a working copy"

Comment: @tanujdave If you get this error, it means .svn directory can not be found, then you just remove the dir by `rm -rf /var/svn/myproject`.